# Creating a ruby-2.2 on Openshift

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, openshift-cartridge

Was anyone able to create a Diy cartridge in OpenShift with Ruby 2.2?

If so can you share with us how? Or if there is any plans on having Ruby 2.2 as a default cartridge?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Openshift3 changed the way they build cartages, they build cartages from docker images now.

Here is how you can build ruby-2.2 deployment environment:
https://blog.openshift.com/deploying-ruby-applications-on-openshift-3/

Answer (score 0):

Pretty old question provided OpenShift v2 is close to EOL. But I thought to share [how I made RAILS 5 app work on v2](https://github.com/akostadinov/ownthat/tree/OSOv2).

The key points is to:

- use the DIY cart
- create start/stop/deploy hooks that install ruby 2.3 by rvm, etc.
- possibly use alternative gems

But too long to paste all scripts here. It involves a hack or two to make RVM happy. I'd suggest looking at [last commit of this branch](https://github.com/akostadinov/ownthat/commit/OSOv2) to see my action-hooks from that commit and possibly borrow from there.

+1 to suggestion to plan on deploying on v3 if possible.